# Windows App Certification Kit ARM not executing on Surface RT

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-rt, wack

I am trying to verify my Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 (developed on VS 2013) on a Surface RT with Windows RT 8.1 Preview, using the Windows Application Certification Kit for ARM.  The problem is that I havent managed to run it not even a single time.

- I successfully installed the ARM Kits Policy Information

To prove it, I ran the following command on the Surface, getting the shown result:

> PS C:> Get-SecureBootPolicy
>
> Publisher: 77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b  Version  : 1

- The Windows App Certification Kit shows under the Start menu but when I run it as Adminstrator I get an error that the digital certificate (signature, since I have the Surface RT in German) can not be verified; and therefore, never executes.

Note: I dont have Visual Studio installed on the Surface and I didnt manage to install any standalone SDK yet my understanding is that within the ARM Kits Policy and SDK is already available.  Could someone confirm this?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a developer license on your Windows 8.1 RT device before you can run your app.

To do this, run the following command in Windows PowerShell (make sure you are run it as an Adminstrator) -

Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration

Refer to this link for more information - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx